# perl getoptions multiple values

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I am trying to parse command line options and values in my script.  The script accepts 2 options: `updategroup` or `validategroup`. The `updategroup` option should accept 2 values.  For example:

`./script.pl -updategroup 'group1' 'enable'`

This is how I call `GetOptions`:

```
GetOptions(\%args,"updategroup=s{2}","validategroup=s");
```

After calling it, I would like to store the 2 values in an array.  How to fetch this value from the `%args` hash variable?

Answer (score 5):

For the repeat specifier to work, the target must already be an array reference:

```
use Getopt::Long;    
my %args = ( updategroup => [] );
GetOptions(\%args, "updategroup=s{2}","validategroup=s");
```